# Show ports in use on Catalyst 3570

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, switchport

I picked up a used C3570 and am new to IOS.  I am trying to ask the switch to show which ports are in use.  My searches lead to the command "show modules" but that's refused by the switch (and command line help suggests no such command)

I have been unable to find the command - if there is one.  Can someone offer the closest command(s) which would show which of the 24 ports are plugged in, perhaps the IP/MAC's on the other side of that port, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
show interface status
```

If you want to see MAC addresses

```
show mac address [dynamic]
```

For a specific interface:

```
show mac address [dynamic] interface <interface-name>
```

For a specific vlan:

```
show mac address [dynamic] vlan <vlan number>
```

Comment: There is also the `show mac-address-table` command, although on some switches it is `show mac address-table`. Cisco added a dash in there at one point.

Answer (score 0):

```
show interface
show interface status
show interface status | inc connected
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the interface status on switch to know which interfàce are on used

`Switch(config)# show interfàce brief`

This  command displays  interfàce status on switch

To find  more visibility of specific interfàce

`interfàce ethernet 0/1`